# What is the best monadic type to explain monad typeclass?

Tags: haskell, monads

What is the best monadic type to explain monad typeclass to some people who don't know anything about monads? Should I use something from standart Haskell library or should I make up some new type?

Comment: The simpler the better, perhaps start with Maybe? I suppose it depends on what you're really trying to show them

Comment: I don't think one monad is enough to actually "get it". Assuming the end goal is that they can read functions typed `Monad m => ... m ...`, not just those involving `TheSpecificMonadYouChose a`.

Comment: For practical purposes I think a combination of `ReaderT` and `WriterT` to produce a "writing and reading" computation.

Comment: Start simple, with `Maybe`, is my suggestion. Most people grok `Maybe` so easily that they start asking themselves, "Wait, is that all there is? What's the big fuss about?" Then you can introduce the list monad as a sort of "generalised Maybe" to turn the difficulty up a notch. What's next I'm not qualified to say.

Comment: What is your audience?  What is their experience and knowledge?

Comment: My path to enlightenment was Maybe -> Either -> [] -> Reader at which point it clicked, Just show them examples until they start to see how they're connected

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, you should read [You could have invented monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html), which walks through three diverse problems and shows how they are all tied together by the same underlying thread: monads.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to motivate monads is to show how many embedded domain specific languages have the structure of a monad:

- List comprehensions are the obvious example.
- JS Promises are a monad with `.then` serving as the bind operation
- Groovy's `?.` operator
- many "fluent" interfaces in O-O languages are monadic

Using monads you can embed an assembler for the 6502 into your program [link](http://www.wall.org/~lewis/2013/10/15/asm-monad.html) or even BASIC code [link](http://augustss.blogspot.de/2009/02/more-basic-not-that-anybody-should-care.html)

The monad pattern allows you to drive out the inessential complexity from your code concentrate on the important details of the computation.

Understanding the monad pattern will serve you well when you want to create you own EDSLs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Maybe` monad is (in my opinion) the easiest to understand.  Once you get passed the concept of the (simple) algebraic type, understanding how the `Maybe` monad works is fairly straightforward.

If someone is having trouble understanding the constructors for `Maybe`, you could write them a class that does the essentially the same thing:

```py
class Maybe(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.__just = value

    def just(self):
        if self.isJust():
            return self.__just
        else:
            raise ValueError('None')

    def isJust(self):
        return self.__just is not None

    def fmap(self, f):
        if self.isJust():
            return Maybe(f(self.just()))
        else:
            return Maybe()

    def bind(self, fM):
        """fM must return a value of type Maybe"""
        if self.isJust():
            return fM(self.just())
        else:
            return Maybe()

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.isJust():
            return 'Just ({})'.format(self.just())
        else:
            return 'Nothing'


def head(some_list):
    if len(some_list) == 0:
        return Maybe()
    else:
        return Maybe(some_list[0])

def idx(some_list, i):
    if idx < len(some_list):
        return Maybe(some_list[i])
    else:
        return Maybe()


print head([1, 2, 3]).bind(
    lambda x: Maybe(2 * x)).bind(
    lambda x: Maybe(x + 1)).bind(
    lambda x: Maybe(x + 3))

print head([[1, 2, 3]]).bind(
    lambda xs: idx(xs, 0)).bind(
    head).bind(
    lambda x: 2 * x)

print head([[1, 2, 3]]).bind(
    lambda xs: idx(xs, 1)).bind(
    head).bind(
    lambda x: 2 * x)
```

This code will print out

```
Just (6)
Nothing
Nothing
```

And this has the same functionality (more or less) as the `Maybe` monad in Haskell, just re-implemented in Python using a class.  The `return` function in Haskell is replaced by the constructor and `>>=` is replaced by `.bind`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to let monadic patterns arise from actual use. It can be enlightening to pick a few types and direct someone toward problems which are naturally expressed by a monadic pattern.

Off the top of my head, it's very easy to argue for the benefits of `Maybe`, have someone get concerned about the nested error handling that obviously results, and then talk about how

```
case f x of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just y -> case g y of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just z -> case h z of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just q -> case r q of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just end -> end
```

is actually a very, very common pattern that Haskell lets you abstract over.

Then talk about configuration and how it's useful to pass a `Config` data type to many functions for them to operate. It's easy to end up writing code like

```
go config in = 
  let (x, y) = f config $ g config $ h config in
  in  finally config x (we'reDone config y)
```

but this is again a very common pattern in Haskell that gets annoying but has a common strategy for mitigating the verbosity.

Finally, talk about mutation of state as chaining endomorphisms like

```
let state4 = (modify4 . modify3 . modify2 . modify1 :: State -> State) state0
```

and how that's pretty annoying as well while also fixing your "modification chain" ahead of time without allowing you to get any information out of the intermediate steps (without, at least, threading it along with your state as well).

And again, this can be solved very uniformly in Haskell by a common abstraction pattern with a weird name. You've heard stories about Monads, right?

Answer (score 0):

One of the more profound insights I had, was that monads can be seen as imperative programming languages, which you can compose. So maybe you should build a "language" with them, so they get a grip of how powerful the abstraction is.

I think creating a programming language for them would be a good perspective.

For example, first you add state

```
import Data.Map as M 
import Control.Monad 
import Control.Monad.State 
data Variable = IntV Int | StringV String .. 
type Context = M.Map String Variable 
type Program a = State Context a
```

Then you add logging:

type Program a = WriterT [String] (State Context) a 
   log x = tell [x]

Then you add exceptions:

type Program a = WriterT [String] (StateT Context Either) a

Then you add continuations etc.

This way you can show them that you can use monads to build an environment which is precisely good for your problem. After this if they are interested you show them the anatomy of a monad and how they are built.

For example first you show the  Maybe monad. Give them first the pure lambda version of it:

```
data Perhaps a = Sure a | Nope
next (Sure a) f = f a
next (Nope) f = Nope
```

Show them how you can chain computations with lambda's:

```
small x | x < 100 = Sure x 
        | otherwise = Nope 
between x y z | x  < z < y = Sure z 
              | otherwise = Nope 

small 10 `next` (\b -> between 5 20 b)
```

Then show them how you can transform this to do notation:

```
small x `next` (\b -> between 5 20 b
        `next` (\c -> between 10 14 c))
```

Suggest it would be handy if we could write it like this:

```
small x -> \b ->
between 5 20 b -> \c -> 
between 10 14 c
```

Then introduce do notation:

```
 b <- small x 
 c <- between 5 20 b 
 between 10 14 c
```

Now they have invented do notation with you from there you can explain some other monads.